# Spring starter project bringing an error while project get created

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am Creating a demo project using Spring starter project, through eclipse, and I am including Web, Actuator and Webtools into this demo project. As the dependencies downloaded, the demo project is showing an error in pom.xml, and error message is the below one:

```
***" Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Failure to transfer org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3 from/to central 
     (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3 
     from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates 
     are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org at "***
```

Note: these are just few first lines.

IDE and JDK details:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

JDK 1.8

I tried to update the eclipse and plugin, but that update process also remained unsuccessful.

I created multiple demo project, with varying combination of dependencies, I found that this error is coming with Actuator dependency.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml? and, what happens when you try to run mvn clean install?

Comment: This issue got fixed, While creating project, the Spring Boot version was 2.xx, when I changed it to 1.5.xx, then there was no more this issue. Some there is another one now.